# How to use restricted templates?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I'm working with the following classes:

```
template<class I, class O>
class TE {...}; //This is an abstract class

template<class I, class O>
class TESO: public TE {...};

template<class I, class O>
class TEMO: public TE {...};
```

Now I want to create a new class `TQ` which should be initialized like this:

```
TQ<int,bool, TESO<int,bool>> tq1;
TQ<int,bool, TEMO<int,bool>> tq2;
```

And I'm not sure what is the correct way to write the `TQ` class.

I'm thinking about this:

```
template<class I, class O, TE<I,O>>
class TQ {
private:
    std::vector< TE<I,O> > TEs;
public:
...
};
```

But I'm not totally sure, as I have compilation errors with:

```
template<class I, class O, TE<I,O>>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TE<I,O>& tq) {
    os << ":" << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: `: protected TE` - you mean `: protected TE<I, O>`? (Also, `protected` inheritance is a rather odd choice.)

Comment: Will be fixed and updated in a minute.

Comment: What exactly is the restriction you want?  And why?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to make the `TE<I,O>` template parameter of the class `TQ` a ["template template parameter"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

As follows:

```
template<class I, class O, template <typename, typename> class TE>
```

This allows the template class `TE` to be used in your template class `TQ` as a template; i.e. it allows you to write code as you have there `TE<I,O>` in `std::vector< TE<I,O> > TEs;` and not just `std::vector< TE > TEs;` (see below).

Alternatively, if the types used in `TE` and not specifically required to be the same as used in `TQ`, then a simple third parameter would;

```
template<class I, class O, class TE>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename I, typename O, template<typename, typename> class TE>
class TQ {
    std::vector< TE<I,O> > TEs;
};


TQ<int, bool, TESO> tq1;
TQ<int, bool, TEMO> tq2;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cd4c4d3a99d28f2)

Also I would rather choose another name for template parameter `TE` to avoid confusion with original `class TE`, though even now it can be accessed from inside `TQ` class as `::TE<...>`.

Answer (score 1):

An other alternative is:

```
template <typename T> class TQ;

// specialization
template <typename I, typename O, template <typename, typename> class C>
class TQ<C<I, O>>
{
    // Your implementation.
};
```

And then use it:

```
TQ<TESO<int,bool>> tq1;
TQ<TEMO<int,bool>> tq2;
```

**EDIT**:

As you require to have `TQ<int, bool, TESO<int, bool>>`, you may use instead:

```
template <typename I, typename O, typename T> class TQ
{
    // cannot be static_assert(false, ""),
    // The condition need to be dependent of template type
    // to have the error when we want
    static_assert(sizeof(I) == 0, "Bad type");
};

// specialization
template <typename I, typename O, template <typename, typename> class C>
class TQ<I, O, C<I, O>>
{
    // Your implementation.
};
```

And then use it as you specified:

```
TQ<int, bool, TESO<int, bool>> tq1;
TQ<int, bool, TEMO<int, bool>> tq2;
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Z1xLr8)

Any type which doesn't match (as `TQ<int, int, TESO<int, bool>>` ) will provoke a compile time error

Comment: It is mandatory for me to support:
TQ<int,bool, TESO<int,bool>> tq1;
TQ<int,bool, TEMO<int,bool>> tq2;

Comment: @Doppelganger: answer edited to match your requirement.

Comment: I'm still getting compilation errors:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfthrwfaon78hfs/Screenshot%202014-09-22%2021.22.46.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/313lxxifbrybia3/Screenshot%202014-09-22%2021.31.21.png?dl=0

Comment: @Doppelganger: For your first example, missing `class` keyword. For the second, the template is missing.

Comment: I wrote it exactly as you suggested but still getting:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/58c76hb5gf7ncv9/Screenshot%202014-09-23%2015.36.43.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uk4hhtcxal9g1um/Screenshot%202014-09-23%2015.32.48.png?dl=0

Comment: @Doppelganger: There is a live example in my answer, if you can reproduce your error using ideone or other online compiler, I may help. (image is not a good tool to display code/error in our case). From your error, it seems that `TESO` is not a template class.